# Drawing a while loop inside a UML Sequence Diagram?

Tags: while-loop, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm currently in the system design phase of my product. I'm using Microsoft Visio Professional 2013. My question is what is the best way to draw a while loop within a sequence diagram?

I have a few of these to create, I've attempted to create one already which is my perspective of what a while loop would look like, I am not sure and I don't want to carry on with disbelief it's right. If you could clarify/correct or give me pointers of the actual syntax needed, I would be very grateful. See below for my attempt.

[image: My Attempt]

**EDIT 1**: Tried Again (still not sure if this is right)

[image]

Comment: Generally you should avoid drawing loops in SDs. Code is a better place for that. I had several posts here related to fragments in SDs.

Comment: Great, i'll have a look thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...or give me pointers...

Generally you should avoid creating `UML` models with picture drawing tools. All of the serious [UML modeling tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools) I've evaluated were able to draw the `UML` things syntactically correct almost automatically (although some have tough RTFM requirements).

If you're looking for `UML` Sequence Diagram reference, then I use mostly [uml-diagrams.org: Sequence Diagrams Reference](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-reference.html) (after reviewing [uml-diagrams.org: UML Sequence Diagrams Examples](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html))

See also

- words "*notation*" and "*sequence diagram*" in [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/)

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of the system should be better drawn .You should widen it to make your diagram more representative and meaningful.

Comment: Okay. Thankyou for the pointer. but am i doing the while loop properly?

Comment: He just means that the fragment should overlap the life lines. Else your drawing is ok.